# Significance of two trigonometric function in theory of numbers:

Tags: generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, riemann-zeta

There are two trigonometric function that pops here and there  in theory of number ( mostly in conjectural forms):

1.$$g(x)=\frac {\sin(πx)}{πx}$$
2. $$ f(x) =\frac {xg'(x)}{g(x)}= (1/2)(πx\cot(πx)-1)$$

In the following fields they appear :

1. Sato - Tate measure , Pair correlation of zeroes of zeta,
   Hilbert - Polya
2. Generating function for $\zeta(2n)$ and other zeta generating function.

The only significance I can see for the given functions is that (1) has all non zero integers as zeroes and (2) has  integers as poles ( Euler formula for infinite partial decomposition )

> > Question : What are some Other non- trivial significant properties of the functions in context of number theory ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as it is. $\sin(x)$ and $1/(e^{2i\pi x}-1)$ appear everywhere in maths, even more in complex analysis. Yes, things related to the residue theorem imply that we can understand them in term of their zeros/poles/residues and growth/decay.

Comment: @renus thank you for the comment but I'm asking for the properties of the functions in context of number theory .

Comment: $\sin {\pi x}$ is a smooth function that stands in well for $||x||$ (distance to closest integer) or {$x$}